# Facing error : OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use: ('', 8089)

Tags: python, server, locust, oserror

I'm trying to run locust and after successfully running it for the first time I did some changes in my locustfile.py . After running the locust command it is giving error"  OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use: ('', 8089)" . have tried killing the PID and it doesn't work. I'm using Linux 18.04 system.
Sharing the complete log trace:

```
[2020-06-23 14:22:25,687] sonali-Latitude-3490/WARNING/locust.main: System open file limit setting is not high enough for load testing, and the OS wouldnt allow locust to increase it by itself. See https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/installation.html#increasing-maximum-number-of-open-files-limit for more info.
[2020-06-23 14:22:25,687] sonali-Latitude-3490/INFO/locust.main: Starting web interface at http://:8089
[2020-06-23 14:22:25,694] sonali-Latitude-3490/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 1.0.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 854, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/locust/web.py", line 288, in start
    self.server.serve_forever()
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 398, in serve_forever
    self.start()
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 336, in start
    self.init_socket()
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 1500, in init_socket
    StreamServer.init_socket(self)
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 180, in init_socket
    self.socket = self.get_listener(self.address, self.backlog, self.family)
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 192, in get_listener
    return _tcp_listener(address, backlog=backlog, reuse_addr=cls.reuse_addr, family=family)
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 288, in _tcp_listener
    sock.bind(address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use: ('', 8089)
2020-06-23T08:52:25Z <Greenlet at 0x7fcb12f1f148: <bound method WebUI.start of <locust.web.WebUI object at 0x7fcb12ef2668>>> failed with OSError

[2020-06-23 14:22:25,696] sonali-Latitude-3490/CRITICAL/locust.web: Unhandled exception in greenlet: <Greenlet at 0x7fcb12f1f148: <bound method WebUI.start of <locust.web.WebUI object at 0x7fcb12ef2668>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 854, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/locust/web.py", line 288, in start
    self.server.serve_forever()
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 398, in serve_forever
    self.start()
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 336, in start
    self.init_socket()
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 1500, in init_socket
    StreamServer.init_socket(self)
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 180, in init_socket
    self.socket = self.get_listener(self.address, self.backlog, self.family)
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 192, in get_listener
    return _tcp_listener(address, backlog=backlog, reuse_addr=cls.reuse_addr, family=family)
  File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 288, in _tcp_listener
    sock.bind(address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use: ('', 8089)
[2020-06-23 14:22:25,696] sonali-Latitude-3490/INFO/locust.main: Running teardowns...
[2020-06-23 14:22:25,696] sonali-Latitude-3490/INFO/locust.main: Shutting down (exit code 2), bye.
[2020-06-23 14:22:25,696] sonali-Latitude-3490/INFO/locust.main: Cleaning up runner...
 Name                                                          # reqs      # fails     Avg     Min     Max  |  Median   req/s failures/s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregated                                                         0     0(0.00%)       0       0       0  |       0    0.00    0.00

Percentage of the requests completed within given times
 Type                 Name                                                           # reqs    50%    66%    75%    80%    90%    95%    98%    99%  99.9% 99.99%   100%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Something else, maybe an other locust instance, is already running on that port.

Comment: yes, @KlausD. I kill the PID with command kill -9 <PID>, it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well...

The sockets are not closing immediately by default. There's a "gentle" period handled by the kernel, which is associated to the SO_LINGER value. See for example http://deepix.github.io/2016/10/21/tcprst.html

It means that you need to "wait a bit" before your server socket becomes available again.

An example on how to handle this in python is given in https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/67443/socket.SO_LINGER.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information!!, i'll try to implement that For now, I was able to kill the PID by command `kill -9 <PID>`